# How to use raw Buffer in Chainlink Functions?

Tags: javascript, chainlink

Chainlink Functions currently offer some encoding functions for string, uint256 and int256, but it actually makes sense to send bytes to solidity in scenarios where for example you need to send multiple parameters or information so you can send it abi encoded.

Functions always need to return a Buffer, so if the provided encoders are not used you need to create your own buffer. For doing that in JS `Buffer.from` can be used, which works perfectly in Chainlink Functions Playground but it fails in practice when the function is used.

For my specific use case I want to do:

```js
return Buffer.from(hexstring, 'hex');
```

where hexstring is my abi encoded data I want to send to the contract.

The error I got is:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'from')

I have also tried the old form of using Buffer like

```js
return new Buffer(hexstring, 'hex');
```

which also works in the playground, but the error this time was that Buffer is not a constructor.

Given that it simply seems to not be imported one idea will be to just add a `require` in the Function but `require`s are not allowed, so it is not the way to go.

Comment: So where are you running this code from?  Node?  Browser?  Buffer isn't a thing in the browser.  Node has a Buffer class which maybe the playground has ported it over, but it would be absent in other environments.  That would explain what you are seeing.

Comment: The code is executed on Chainlink decentralized oracle n but there is not much info about the nodes in that network (DON) but I haven't found much details about them. In here https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/api-reference/javascript-source it says anything vanilla Deno is supported and it seems to me Buffer is included in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using one of the encoding tools provided, Chainlink Functions request source code must return a Uint8Array, which represents the bytes that are returned on-chain. You should not need to use the Deno buffer library for this, as Deno natively supports [Uint8Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) without any imports.

As an example, try:

```
const myArr =  new Uint8Array(ARRAY_LENGTH)
```

Comment: When returning Uint8Array in the playground I get "Error: returned value not a Buffer". Is it going to work when deployed?

Comment: Chainlink Functions Playground runs in the browser and is not a replica of the environment in which your code will be executed when run on the DON.  To run the test in a 1:1 environment, I'd recommend using the [Functions Toolkit](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/smart-contract-examples) or [Functions Hardhat Starter Kit](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-hardhat-starter-kit).  What is provided above should work in production.

Comment: @e1Ru1o as per  Maxwell's suggestion, use simulateScript1() from the Functions Toolkit. It requires you have a local instance of Deno on your machine.  But it is the most "faithful" replication of the Functions environment.  The front end browser version has similar APIs but is not a full Deno instance (being in-browser).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Deno doesn't support `Buffer.from`.  It has `Buffer`, but it doesn't line up with Node it seems.

Here are the docs: https://deno.land/api@v1.38.5?s=Deno.Buffer

Also it's deprecated so maybe you could use a different API and have more luck with it.

Comment: Thanks. I still need to return a `Buffer` as mentioned in the chainlink functions documentation so I will need to check how to work with that Buffer provided by Deno even if deprecated.

Comment: I see they also have a node like buffer version https://deno.land/x/node_buffer@1.1.0

Comment: Yea that looks like an external lib to Deno so if you defined that dependency maybe it'd fix your code as now it'd support `Buffer.from`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import Buffer this way:

`const { Buffer } = await import("node:buffer")`

for istance:

```
// this is to test how we can call our api, making a call to the healthcheck
const { Buffer } = await import("node:buffer")
// make HTTP request
const url = `https://8c21-93-67-103-124.ngrok-free.app/parse-robots-txt?url=https://www.google.com`; // Update with an ngrock
console.log(`HTTP GET Request to ${url}`);

// construct the HTTP Request object. See: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-hardhat-starter-kit#javascript-code

const request = Functions.makeHttpRequest({
  url: url,
});
// Execute the API request (Promise)
const response = await request;

if (response.error) {
  console.error(response.error);
  throw Error("Request failed");
}

return Buffer.from(response.data, "hex")
```

I suggest to try out using [examples here](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-hardhat-starter-kit#javascript-code)

source: https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/node/compatibility